# Colorbox Load Specific div from iFrame

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox, and I want to load a specific div from another page on the website. Right now I'm using an iFrame, but I guess it doesn't necessarily have to be an iFrame, since I'm staying on the same website. My code right now is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, data:"#mainColumn", width:"80%", height:"80%"});
});

<a class="iframe cboxIframe" href="http://website.com/products-51>.html">
```

I need to load the page in the `href` into the Colorbox, but only display the `#mainColumn` div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ColorBox leverages jQuery's `.load()` method for handling ajax. If you are loading a document from the same domain as your current document, you can use a selector pull out just the portion of the document that is needed. I am assuming the container which you want from other page is `#mainColumn`

```
var $iframe = $(".iframe");
$(".iframe").colorbox({ 
    href: $(".iframe").attr('href') + " #mainColumn",
});
```

Comment: Yes, I just need to load and display the content inside #mainColumn...I tried the code, as of now it's not working. I sort of understand what your code is doing, but can't get it to work. Hmm

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very, very much! I tell you, this website is such an amazing help :)

Comment: How would this work for multiple anchors with the class of iframe ... this code seems to load only the href from the first item. Thanks.