# Colorbox Ajax Loading of external page but only a specific Div

Tags: colorbox

hopefully someone has done this before...

Im trying to load an external page using Colorbox and its Ajax function.

using a ajax link from the example at colorbox you use a link like so:

```
<p><a class='ajax' href="../content/ajax.html" title="Homer Defined">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
```

This will load that page ajax.html into your page with the colorbox overlay, What I would like to do is load a specific div in the ajax.html. so something like:

```
<p><a class='ajax' href="../content/ajax.html#ThisDivOnly" title="Homer Defined">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
```

so only loading the DIV: #ThisDivOnly

have tried the above but no love.

Help appreciated. First time post. :)

Comment: For best response, post your js statements that call ColorBox, as well. That way, we can review the association being made between your anchor link and the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out this question: [Colorbox Load Specific div from iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025937/colorbox-load-specific-div-from-iframe)

Looks like it's answered pretty well in there.