# Colorbox iframe - hide specific div (breadcrumb)

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I'm using the jquery colorbox plugin, and I'm loading internal pages from my website into an `iframe`.

This pages could also be load directly, from a google search for example.

There is a breadcrumb on these pages. I want to hide the breadcrumb when the page is load as an iframe, because the breadcrumb is unnecessary. The breadcrumb is only useful if people access directly to the page.

I have read the question: [Colorbox iframe - loading specific div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365710/colorbox-iframe-loading-specific-div-only) and tried to hide a specific div but it doesn't work.

I have also read this question on [Colorbox: loading specific div from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025937/colorbox-load-specific-div-from-iframe) and tried to load only the div below the breadcrumb.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to hide the breadcrumb when the page is load in the colorbox.
you have to put fastIframe to false and add a onComplete function.

> $(document).ready(function(){
>       $(".iframe").colorbox({
>           iframe:true, 
>           fastIframe:false, 
>           onComplete: function() { 
>           $("iframe").contents().find("#backlinks").css("display","none");
>           }
>       });
>   });