# jQuery Colorbox: Trouble loading single ID through ajax (not the full page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm trying to load a form named `#submit-text-form` through jQuery colorbox. However, colorbox ends up loading the entire page that the original link is targeting. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025937/colorbox-load-specific-div-from-iframe) but it is still loading the full page. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

```
$(function(){
$('#submit-link').colorbox({
opacity: 0.3,
transition: 'fade',
href: $("#submit-link").attr('href') + "#submit-text-form",
});
});
```

Comment: Is there an element with that ID on the target page?

Comment: is there displaying any errors in the firebug

Comment: @muthu nope :/ seems to be happening with any element I try to call from colorbox

Comment: Can you check whether all tags are get closed?

Comment: Can u  upload ur code in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
$('#submit-link').colorbox({
opacity: 0.3,
transition: 'fade',
href: $("#submit-link").attr('href') + " #submit-text-form",
});
})
```

There needs to be a space before the your selector `" #submit-text-form`.  Colorbox uses jQuery's load() method for ajax handling, so it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the page which should be shown in the colorbox directly from your browser, you should see only the page inside. if not, and still have to load the full page and display one portion of it, get the data with ajax, on success get the required portion with DOM selectors, and then show it inside the colorbox.

Like this:

```
$.get($("#submit-link").attr('href'), 
    function(response) {
        //Load the AJAX response into a jQuery variable
        var $html = $(response);
        //Get the portion which you need to show inside the colorbox
        $html.find('#submit-text-form').colorbox({ opacity: 0.3, transition: 'fade');
        //Append it to body. (I didn't use colorbox before.)
        $('body').append($html);
});
```

**Note**: I didn't test it, I didn't use colorbox before, but this is the way you want I think.

Comment: I don't follow the last sentence :/