# Is it possible to load only part of a page using colorbox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025937/colorbox-load-specific-div-from-iframe), I have been attempting to load only part of a page using colorbox. My code looks like this. I have a web page with a bunch of content, but contains also a specific div with an id:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<div id="colorboxcontent">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I try to load this *part* of the page using colorbox, like so:

```
$('a').colorbox({
  href: $(this).attr('href') + ' #colorboxcontent'
});
```

According to the question/answer linked above this should work because colorbox uses the jquery ajax load method, which makes it possible to pull in specific parts of a page. This however does not work for me. I get an error stating that the content failed to load.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that instead of `href` you can use `html` and directly load in the contents of said div tag.

edit: You could have a hidden div on the page to 'process' the Ajax below in:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "[your_page_url]",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var htmlData = $.parseHTML(data);
        $("#myhiddendiv").html(htmlData);

        //now your original div exists on the page
        $('a').colorbox({
            html: $("#colorboxcontent").html();
        });

        //if you want to you could clear that temp div now
        $("myhiddendiv").html("");
    }
 });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: cheers for the heads up! I edited my post originally (it was short) and overwrote the above fixed code by accident!

Comment: okay, however this isn't working for me :( . colorbox is loading the page referenced in the anchor's href, but it's still loading the whole page. i think the case you are indicating might work if i'm trying to load content from the  current page?

Comment: Ah ok, so you would need to load the page via Ajax then with that resulting html, filter to the particular html of the element `#colorboxcontent`

Comment: this new edit is an interesting idea. the problem is that i have a bunch of colorbox links on the page. running all those ajax calls at page load could be problematic. i might try it though... thanks for your ideas @scgough!

Comment: No problem. Yea, understood - the wider picture of what you've got going on within your page might cause efficiency issues. Let me know how you get on and upvote/mark if it helps! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I responded to your on the Colorbox's issue tracker, but replying here for the SO folks. I think what you posted looks fine, so my current impression is that there is an unrelated issue that is keeping this from working:

It could be an unrelated JS error or invalid markup.

My guess is that the page you are testing is not being hosted by a server.  The website needs to be hosted by a http server for ajax calls to work properly, rather than just opening the html file in a browser.

Comment: I was testing this on a server running on my local dev machine. I wasn't able to get it working and ended up loading the content from a separate php file. Not sure what answers to mark as correct here as I was personally not able to get this working. Perhaps if this is a tested and approved functionality it should be included in the colorbox docs?